# Use name_get in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

How to concatenate Many2one field, open drop down list all car is visible.  I need [id] and [name].

For example:

[01] Audi,

[02] BMW

```py
car_id = fields.Many2one('my.cars', 'Cars')


@api.multi
    def name_get(self):

???
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with following:

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for record in self:
        name = '[' + str(record.id) + ']' + ' ' + record.name
        result.append((record.id, name))
    return result
```

Note:

*name_get()* method must be set on *my.cars* object.

Comment: I would prefer `name = "[{}] {}".format(record.id, record.name)` or `name = "[%i] %s" % (record.id, record.name)`. Why --> [That's why](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/why-is-s-better-than-for-concatenation)